# Deeply compact nested hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Given the following hash structure...

```
{
  a: nil,
  b: [],
  c: {c1: {c2: nil}},
  d: [{d1: "Value!"}],
  e: "Value!",
  f: {f1: {f2: nil, f3: "Value!"}}
}
```

I'd like to be able to return...

```
{
  d: [{d1: "Value!"}],
  e: "Value!",
  f: {f1: {f3: "Value!"}}
}
```

So the rules would be
  1) Remove any key that points to a `nil`, `{}`, or `[]` value
  2) Remove any key that leads to value which points to an empty value (example `c:` from the original hash)
  3) Preserve the outer key if one or more inner keys point to a non empty value, but remove inner keys that point to an empty value. (see `f:` and notice that `f2:` is removed)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Okay. what have you tried to solve this? What issues do you have with your solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could have some fun with monkey-patching the core classes involved:

```
class Object
  def crush
    self
  end
end

class Array
  def crush
    r = map(&:crush).compact

    r.empty? ? nil : r
  end
end

class Hash
  def crush
    r = each_with_object({ }) do |(k, v), h|
      if (_v = v.crush)
        h[k] = _v
      end
    end

    r.empty? ? nil : r
  end
end
```

It's an unusual thing to want to do, but if you do need it done writing a method like `crush` might help.

Comment: I like this approach. It seems to work with the exception of the Array#crush method. An array with a hash that has keys with empty values don't get compacted.  I'm going to play around for a bit to see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 6):

This should be a one pass operation that works with nested arrays and hashes:

```rb
CRUSHABLE = [nil, [], {}].freeze
def crush(thing)
  if thing.is_a?(Array)
    thing.each_with_object([]) do |v, a|
      v = crush(v)
      a << v unless CRUSHABLE.include?(v)
    end
  elsif thing.is_a?(Hash)
    thing.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), h|
      v = crush(v)
      h[k] = v unless CRUSHABLE.include?(v)
    end
  else
    thing
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  def deep_compact(hash)
    res_hash = hash.map do |key, value|
      value = deep_compact(value) if value.is_a?(Hash)

      value = nil if [{}, []].include?(value)
      [key, value]
    end

    res_hash.to_h.compact
  end
```

Comment: This function recursively compacts the input hash.